# Migrating wordpress server and use the old database

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, phpmyadmin

I have to migrate the files from a website in Wordpress to a new server, however I would like the database to stay on the old server.

```
I tried to 'wp-config.php' change 'localhost' to panel PHPmyadmin: 'http://admin.*****.com/mysql/' put me back: Error Establishing a database connection.
```

the users and passwords'm sure that is correct, the url I'm not sure, Its possible?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If on shared hosting, you most likely have to enable 'Remote MySQL' to allow for external connection to the database.  Check with your host to see if you have access to this feature or for documentation.

[GoDaddy Connecting Remotely to Shared Hosting Databases](http://support.godaddy.com/help/article/4978/connecting-remotely-to-shared-hosting-databases)

[Hostgator](http://support.hostgator.com/articles/specialized-help/technical/managing-your-database-with-applications)

Answer (score 0):

If the database stays on the old server you have to change `localhost` in the wp-config.php on the new server to the MySQL-Server-Address of the old server