# cPanel, How to connect to my Database

Tags: config, cpanel, hostname

I created a project and tested in my local server. Now I want to shift to remote server but I can not access my database.Following is what i have already done using google help:

```
1. I uploaded the database. I got name something as : smthd_myDatabase

2. Then i created an user with username : smthd_mysername with password(for example): myPassword


3. Then in config.php i included those info. It looked something as below:

<?php
$mysql_hostname = "10.**.**.***";
$mysql_user = "smthd_mysername";
$mysql_password = "myPassword";
$mysql_database = "smthd_myDatabase";
$bd = mysql_connect($mysql_hostname, $mysql_user, $mysql_password)
or die("Opps some thing went wrong");
mysql_select_db($mysql_database, $bd) or die("Opps some thing went wrong");

?>
```

But still it is not working. When i try to load the page it says can not connect to mySql server. So what should I use as my hostname. Or where I get all those information to use in my config.php file. Or is there anything i am missing. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Try use 'localhost' as the database hostname rather than the IP address of your server. In MySQL a user connecting with username@10.1.1.1 can have different permissions to a user connecting with username@localhost.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have added the user to the database you created.  In cPanel, you would do this under `MySQL Databases`.  At the bottom of the page, select your user and select your database.  Then select permissions for the user.  Most likely you want select `ALL PRIVILEGES`.

After you have done this, if the site is located on the same server then your config should be something like:

```
<?php
$mysql_hostname = "localhost";
$mysql_user = "smthd_mysername";
$mysql_password = "myPassword";
$mysql_database = "smthd_myDatabase";
$bd = mysql_connect($mysql_hostname, $mysql_user, $mysql_password)
    or die("Opps some thing went wrong");
mysql_select_db($mysql_database, $bd) or die("Opps some thing went wrong");
?>
```

Note: if you are using goDaddy or a host equivalent, your MySQL databases may have their own IP.  You should check with your host.  If this is true, you would also have to allow remote connections to the database.  In cPanel, you set this under `Remote MySQL`.  See my answer [here for reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20111217/2812723).

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem on godaddy cpanel yesterday and today. I tried everything. Checked config.php repeatedly, double checked password on the database. Checked the db prefix. 
At noon today, tried switching to godaddy's native 5.4 php and my site was up immediately.